# How to Select All & Copy from a webpage using VBA

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, vba, copy

I am working with an embedded table on a webpage, and am trying to automate the process of copying it into Excel.  A simple "Select All" + Copy + Paste would work perfectly, but I cannot figure out how to automate this using VBA.

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What worked or didn't work with your attempts?

Comment: I tried a macro to get text directly from the object and separate it into lines, but it didn't carry the formatting from the page (columns in the web table were not kept).

I'm puzzled by how difficult it is (for only me, maybe?) to tell Excel to simply execute the "Select All" & "Copy" commands on a webpage that I tell it to open.

Comment: have you tried using the built in [Get External Data From Webpage](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/get-external-data-from-a-web-page-HA010218472.aspx) ?, Another option is to use [Send Keys Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa202943%28v=office.10%29.aspx), another option is to use [IE Automation](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/47b225f9-9561-4577-8673-57309a42f51b/how-to-work-with-internet-explorer-in-excel-vba?forum=exceldev).  Look into these methods, and try them, if you have any more direct issues come back and ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

A way to get data from a webpage into a VBA application is to use a WinHttpRequest object:

```
Dim url, resp As String
Dim req As New WinHttpRequest

url = "http://www.domain.com/page"
req.Open "GET", url, False
req.Send

resp = req.ResponseText
```

The HTML source is stored in the `resp` variable from which you can retrieve the table and its data using string functions and loops to analyze table rows and their formatting and write the data to your worksheet rows.